# Joi validate ignores nested keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, schema, joi

This is my Joi validation:

```
let schema = Joi.object().keys({
  personal_info: Joi.object().keys({
    first_name: Joi.string().min(2).max(10).regex(Regex.alphabeta, 'alphabeta').required().error(JoiCustomErrors),
    last_name: Joi.string().min(2).max(10).regex(Regex.alphabeta, 'alphabeta').required().error(JoiCustomErrors),
    phone: Joi.string().min(10).max(10).regex(Regex.num, 'num').required().error(JoiCustomErrors),
    nickname: Joi.string().min(3).max(12).regex(Regex.alphanum, 'alphanum').required().error(JoiCustomErrors),
    birthday: Joi.date().max(`01-01-${new Date().getFullYear()-8}`).required().error(JoiCustomErrors),
    IDNumber: Joi.string().min(9).max(9).regex(Regex.num, 'num').required().error(JoiCustomErrors),
    address: Joi.object().keys({
      city: Joi.string().valid(Cities).required().error(JoiCustomErrors),
      street: Joi.string().min(2).max(15).regex(Regex.alphabeta, 'alphabeta').required().error(JoiCustomErrors),
      house_number: Joi.string().min(1).max(5).regex(Regex.alphanum, 'alphanum').error(JoiCustomErrors)
    })
  }),
  permission_level: Joi.number().min(1).max(9).required().error(JoiCustomErrors)
});
Joi.validate(req.body, schema, { abortEarly: false }, (err) => {
  if (err) return cast.joiError(err);
  return create_employee(result);
});
```

**Explain:**

All nested keys that are inside `personal_info` object are not getting checked. That means - If I take `first_name` and put it on parent (not under `personal_info`) it's getting checked by the schema validator - as should be.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not clear with the question, can you describe it more with the example.

Comment: All nested keys that are under `personal_info` are not getting checked.
That means - If i take `first_name` and put it on parent (not under `personal_info`) it's getting checked by the schema validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .required() on personal_info schema object and then it will work as you are expecting,

```
'use strict';
const Joi = require('joi');
let schema = Joi.object().keys({
    personal_info: Joi.object().keys({
        first_name: Joi.string().min(2).max(10).required(),
        last_name: Joi.string().min(2).max(10).required()
    }).required(),
    permission_level: Joi.number().min(1).max(9).required()
});
const req = {
    personal_info: {
        first_name: 'AAAA',
        last_name: 'CCCCCC'
    },
    permission_level: 2
};

Joi.validate(req, schema, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: The problem is that in your input you have provided with `personal_info` object. 
However I need that the schema will test even when the input is missing the object at all

Comment: Try removing field last name from my input, it will give an error.

Comment: Updated the answer, check it now, you should use .required() on the personal_info key.

Comment: Yes that is the trick - I have forgot to add `.required()` to the object itself as well.
BTW - in order to fire the required you have to first give a default value to the object so you have to set: `.default({}).required()` as well - add this please so your answer will be the correct answer

Comment: .default({}) is not required to fire the validation.

Comment: Is required to fire validation of the nested keys rather than just getting an error about the object itself, isn't it?